# How to copy a multidimensional integer array into another one

Tags: java, arrays, multidimensional-array

So I have this block of code

```
public class Filter {
   int[][] sourceImage;

public Filter(int[][] image) {

    // TODO store values to sourceImage
   }
}
```

All I want to do here is store the values passed into image to sourceImage. Can someone please help me with how to do that? Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The easiest way would be to just do

```
sourceimage = image;
```

Note that this copies the reference to the array, so both `sourceimage` and the reference passed into the `filter()` method will point to the same array. Any changes made to the array will be visible from both references.

Comment: That may or may not be OK.  In this case, there's only one array, and two references to it.  Modifications to "the original" will be seen in `sourceImage`. That may or may not be desired.  Some discussion of this would be appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

If `sourceImage` must be a distinct array, you can loop through both dimensions and copy each item:

```
sourceImage = new int[image.length][]; // Initialize the first dimension.
for (int i=0; i<sourceImage.length; i++) {
    sourceImage[i] = new int[image[i].length]; // Initialize the 2nd dimension.
    for (int j=0; j<sourceImage[i].length; j++) {
        sourceImage[i][j] = image[i][j]; // Copy each value.
    }
}
```

You can do this a little quicker by making use of `System.arraycopy`, but explicit loops are better for learning :-)

If it's okay that the object's `sourceImage` is **the same array** as the one passed to the constructor, then you can simply assign it. Doing it this way means that any changes to one of the arrays (`image` or `sourceImage`) will **affect them both**, because they are just two references to the same array object.

```
sourceImage = image;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
sourceImage = new int[image.length][];
for (int i=0; i<image.length; i++) {
    sourceImage[i] = Arrays.copyOf(image[i],image[i].length);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

All you have to do is use Arrays.copyOf() method so that the values of image[][] will get copied to sourceImage[][]

```
public class Filter {
   int[][] sourceImage;

public Filter(int[][] image) {

        sourceImage = new int[image.length][];

    for (int i = 0; i < image.length; ++i) {
         sourceImage[i] = Arrays.copyOf(image[i], image[i].length);
     }
   } 

}
```

You have to do this because if you DO THIS

```
sourceImage=image;//(WHICH SHOULD NEVER BE DONE UNLESS YOU ACTUALLY WANT BOTH TO REFER TO THE SAME LOCATION)
```

then if in the program you try to change the value of **image** then the value of **sourceImage** will **change** as they refer to the **same location**

Answer (score -2):

You cannot pass the array. Technically only address is passed between methods.
Instead you can keep the array in a class and send that class as an argument.

class A{
   int arr[] = {1,2,3,4,5};
}

class B{
   A a = new A();
   public A process(A y) {
   }
}

Hope this clarifies your question.

Comment: This is not correct.  You can past an `int[][]` as an argument.